# How to get the value if a date from one dataset is within a period of time in another dataset for each id in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have two datasets, A and B. For dataset A, it has ID, date and Interest. For dataset B, it has ID, date_1, date_2, Int. If date in dataset A is within the range of date_1 and date_2 in dataset B; then I want to extract the value Int in B to the column Interest in A. Here is the sample code that I run. 
But got error message of

```
"Error in if (subset_A[j, ]$date >= subset_B[k, ]$date_1 & subset_A[j,  : 
  argument is of length zero"
```

.

```
A <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), "date" = c("1900-01-01","1900-11-01","1902-01-01","1903-01-01","1905-01-01","1900-01-01"), "Interest" = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
A$date<-as.Date(A$date)
B <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,1,2,2,2,5), 
                "date_1" = c("1900-01-01","1900-02-01","1900-01-01","1901-02-01","1901-03-01","1900-01-01"),
                "date_2" = c("1900-01-03","1903-01-01","1901-01-01","1901-03-01","1904-03-01","1903-01-01"),
                "Int" = c(1,2,1,3,3,1))
B$date_1 <- as.Date(B$date_1)
B$date_2 <- as.Date(B$date_2)
```

In R:

```
IDlist = unique(A$ID)
Table=NULL
for (i in 1:length(IDlist)){
  subset_B <-subset(B, ID == IDlist[i])
  subset_A <-subset(A, ID == IDlist[i])
  for (j in 1:nrow(subset_A)){
    for (k in 1:nrow(subset_B)){
      if(subset_A[j,]$date >=  subset_B[k,]$date_1&
         subset_A[j,]$date <=  subset_B[k,]$date_2&
         !is.na(subset_B[k,]$date_1) & 
         !is.na(subset_B[k,]$date_2))
        subset_A[j,]$Interest <- subset_B[k,]$Int
      Table=rbind(Table,
                  subset_A)
    }
  } 
}
```

I want to get the data frame A with last column inputed as c(1,2,2,3,NA,NA). Not sure why the for loop is not working.Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

With `data.table`'s *non-equi join* and *update in a join* this becomes

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)[, Interest := NULL][
  setDT(B), on = .(ID, date >= date_1, date <= date_2), Interest := Int][]
```

> ```
>    ID       date Interest
> 1:  1 1900-01-01        1
> 2:  1 1900-11-01        2
> 3:  1 1902-01-01        2
> 4:  2 1903-01-01        3
> 5:  2 1905-01-01       NA
> 6:  3 1900-01-01       NA
> ```

Note that the `Interest` column had to be removed from `A` before the *update join* because it was initialized with `NA` which is of type logical while the replacement values are of type double and a vector column can hold data of one type only.

Answer (score 3):

**1)** Using SQL this can be expressed directly:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select A.*, B.Int from A 
  left join B on A.ID = B.ID and A.date between B.date_1 and B.date_2")
```

giving:

```
  ID       date Interest Int
1  1 1900-01-01       NA   1
2  1 1900-11-01       NA   2
3  1 1902-01-01       NA   2
4  2 1903-01-01       NA   3
5  2 1905-01-01       NA  NA
6  3 1900-01-01       NA  NA
```

**2)** If you really want to use a loop then loop through the rows of A and for each one grab the corresponding element in B:

```
Table <- A
for(i in 1:nrow(A)) {
  ix <- which(A$ID[i] == B$ID & A$date[i] >= B$date_1 & A$date[i] <= B$date_2)[1]
  Table$Int[i] <- B$Int[ix]
}
Table
```

giving:

```
  ID       date Interest Int
1  1 1900-01-01       NA   1
2  1 1900-11-01       NA   2
3  1 1902-01-01       NA   2
4  2 1903-01-01       NA   3
5  2 1905-01-01       NA  NA
6  3 1900-01-01       NA  NA
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
fuzzy_left_join(A, B, by = c('ID', 'date' = 'date_1', 'date' = 'date_2'),
           match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`, `<=`)) %>%
   transmute(ID = ID.x, date, Interest = Int)
#   ID       date Interest
#1  1 1900-01-01        1
#2  1 1900-11-01        2
#3  1 1902-01-01        2
#4  2 1903-01-01        3
#5  2 1905-01-01       NA
#6  3 1900-01-01       NA
```